# Xcode error calling -display has no effect

Tags: xcode, uitouch, sprite-sheet, texturepacker

Recently i updated my Xcode to 7, and before doing that I had no problems, but I am currently having an issue with the my Sprite sheets not trimming properly from texture packer when I set it to crop, keep positioning. I have tried changing the z position on sprites. I have searched for days on how to fix this issue and nothing worked. Can someone help me fix this.

Comment: could you provide screenshots for that? maybe hosted externally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using SpriteKit and not Cocos2d...

What exactly is happening? Do you see parts of other sprites? Or are they not positioned correctly.

What did you try to accomplish with settings the z position?

Posting some screenshots would be helpful.

If you can't do that in public please send them to support at codeandweb.com - we are happy to help.

Comment: Yes the positioning of the sprites is way off when I use Crop and Keep Positioning, which did not happen prior to updating Xcode. When I use the trim function it places the sprites correctly but it does not trim them so button textures are clicked no matter what part of the screen I touch.  I tried to change the z positioning because other people who got this <Metallayer> 1a27320404: error calling -display has no effect message said it could be solved by changing the z position.

Comment: I cant send screen shot of the game sorry, and yes i am using SpriteKit.

Comment: Ok - we'll look into it. But since the change is in XCode I don't see much what we can do about it. It simply seems that they broke this feature. :(

Comment: Yep i figured it was Xcode but thanks for your help anyway i really appreciate it.